# What can I do to use my RCX brick?

Tags: rcx

I got this old mindstorms invention system 2.0 and I can't get the tower to connect. I have the right battery and adapter and a working brick. I have tried the Bricx program and it is not working. I don't know much about the situation, so I'm sorry for any lack of information.

I'm wondering if its because I have a 2.0 tower and a 1.0 brick? Or maybe my tower is broken. Is there any sign of the tower being on?
Please tell me if there is something I need to do.

Comment: The tower emits infrared light which you *might* be able to detect with your phone, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Hi Joey, do you have a LEGO serial tower or a LEGO USB tower? You could open a serial terminal program and check if the transmissions are echoed back.